# Sending data to chart in plotly offline mode

Tags: python, plotly

I want to Send data to chart in the plotly offline mode like [this](https://plot.ly/python/sending-data-to-charts/#overwrite-chart-data-with-new-data) example.(or refresh drew a diagram with new data without opening new tabs when I use plotly in a loop that open new tab for each iteration(like ajax refresh data). How can I do this task?
thanks in advance for your helping.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a lot late with answer, but I guess someone would meet same problem some day.

[Here](https://plotly.com/python/v3/sending-data-to-charts/) you could find an example with an old Plotly v3

Here are a few threads for plotly v4 (new one, offline version):

- [Solution for Jupyter notebook](https://community.plotly.com/t/extending-data-to-the-same-plot/19103/2)
- [For Dash (Plotly-sublib for web)](https://community.plotly.com/t/extend-or-append-data-instead-of-update/8898)
- [For R language](https://community.plotly.com/t/what-is-the-most-performant-way-to-update-a-graph-with-new-data/639)

I somehow rewrote those examples for up-to-date version:

```py
fig = go.Figure(layout_title_text='my example chart')
fig = go.Figure(
        data=[{'y': []}],
        layout_title_text="Some layout title"
)

for iteration in range(10):
    fig['data'][0]['y'] += tuple([iteration])

fig.write_html("somefile.html")
```